# Running a Tcl script opens a blank window

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a tcl script that I wrote called perm.tcl I'm trying to run this script on a windows machine.

```
package require Tk

proc invert list {
  set length [llength $list]
  return $length
}

invert {1 2 3 4}
```

Whenever i try to run this code in a command prompt using

```
tclsh perm.tcl
```

a blank activetcl window opens titled "perm" with no text or anything. In this case it should simply output the number 4 but im getting just a small greyed out window. I know this procedure works because when i painstakingly write it out in the tclsh command prompt i get the desired result of 4. Please help

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are importing the Tk package. When you do that, it automatically creates a window. If you don't want any windows, don't import `Tk`.

Comment: When i take out the line requiring the Tk package i dont get any output, it just seems to run the program and not print anything and then prompt me for another command

Comment: @Zac: why would you expect to get output? You aren't printing anything out. If you want to see output, you've got to create output. For example, `puts [invert {1 2 3 4}]`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm extremely new to the tcl language!